# Cursor moves when mouse is plugged in

Tags: windows-7, mouse, cursor

I have a strange problem, where my mouse cursor vibrates at my home, but nowhere else. I've changed my mouse and reinstalled it's drivers.

However, when I unplug my mouse, the vibration stops and the laptop's touch-pad doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Weird. So you're saying the only thing you've correlated with the vibration is your physical location?

Comment: Do you have a mousepad at home, or are you using the mouse on a reflective surface?

Comment: @MarcusChan yes

Comment: @ta.speot.is as i said even the mouse pad is same . also i have changed it no success

Comment: Does that happen in one spot or anywhere in your house?

Comment: @JohnSiu No . i tried everywhere in house . same problem

Comment: Did you plug-in the power adaptor when you test? Try the other way. Also try test on the floor. I wonder if anything to do with power or your house is vibrating.

Comment: I bet that is an optical mouse. Can you try to use a plain white paper as your mouse pad?

Comment: @JohnSiu i already tried plugged or unplugged power no diff . also i tried grounding :(  . and plain white , black , red, yellow etc papers

Comment: Your mouse has problem. Laptop has touchpad which has usually higher priority than mouse to control pointer. There's need of certain degree of movement to override that of touchpad. So, mouse is unable to vibrant it on laptop.

Comment: I understand you can use the same mouse with different laptop with no problem, so could be the USB port. **When did the problem start?** This is a weird one :P

Comment: i don't remember .  more than 6 months .

Comment: @SachinShekhar so the problem should appear everywhere , not just at home

Comment: Not saying these are the answer, just throwing it out there. 
Might be malware/spyware. Your home network lets the software 'phone home' per say, and your work place has a firewall that blocks it. It could just be your routers that are causing the issue. If it's an old laptop/mouse you could try turning on Legacy device support in BIOS. You could disabled the mouse in device manager and restart. Once booted, Let windows install the thing.  Sometimes there's a small button on the USB adapter or under the mouse used to sync the signal. Try doing that. That's all I got.

Answer (score 5):

All these seems unreal. Yesss, ghosts are vibrating your mouse =)

Maybe anything vibrates near the mouse. If not, and if nothing helped,
then simply try to ***boot to another OS***.
It will help you to understand if the problem is in your OS or not.
If it continues to vibrate, then the problem is in your house.
Otherwise (if the problem is in your OS), run *ProcMon.exe* to watch what's happening when it vibrates, and also check autoruns (using *Autoruns.exe*, not msconfig), and check driver/program startup order with *ProcExp.exe* .You can download them in Sysinternals' website.

If after all this your mouse continues to vibrate... then ghosts are vibrating your mouse **:)**
Good Luck!

Comment: Nice idea about booting another OS . i will try an ubuntu live and inform you . but i have already tried sysinternal tools .

Comment: Bad news . the problem exists in Ubuntu , Gparted etc . also the problem exists in "Safe Mode" .

Comment: Now you can be sure that it's not a driver/virus problem. The problem is not in your PC. The problem is in mouse or house :) fix your mouse. Also try another mouse. Or find vibrating things in your house!

Answer (score 3):

### Clean.

First, make sure to clean your mouse optical hole thoroughly, ideally with lens cleanser and lint-free tissue. Different lighting conditions (day/night/fluorescent) between your work and home could cause different behaviors. Modern mouses are very sensitive and it's not always obvious it's a dusty/dirty problem until you clean it.

### Known issues

What is your mouse model? Maybe there are known problems or device incompatibility with it.

### Disable.

Next, I would try to disable EVERY "Mice and other pointing device" in Windows Device Manager. Maybe some unused device driver, or the touchpad itself could be interfering with your mouse.

### Isolate the problem

Approach the issue scientifically. It's okay at work, bad at home.... surely, **something is different** between those 2 places! Try both battery or wall power. At home, try another room away from equipement. Try outside. In the park. Try half-way between your work and your home. Try at work in a meeting room. If it vibrates *everywhere* except your own work desk, ask your boss what he did to your mouse.

### New: Corded vs wireless

Is this a wireless mouse anyway? Try a corded USB mouse. (Or vice-versa).

Comment: Already tried all of your ideas except trying half-way between work and home which is not good option .

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is really challenging. Your hardware is sensible to some interference with some signal that is present in your house. If you have a laptop, you could try and disconnect all the electrical stuff in your house, or even turn the electrical power off.

The signal could also come from outside, say a mobile communications antenna.
It would also be worth trying with a cordless mouse. Maybe the mouse cable acts as an antenna.

I would add that since other laptops don't have the problem, your laptop's EM shielding is flawed. I would report that to the producer and ask for assistence.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, there is a electromagnetic source close to the mouse (sometimes even mobile phone affects).

Comment: i have moved more than 20 meters away but problem still persists .

Comment: also i moved every such devices away . i am happy that you got the point of view .

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the border where the behaviour changes. Does it jitter in the corridor? In front of your door? 20 meters away from the door?

Think about what else is different "at home": Wifi - turn if off. Power connection - unplug it. Direction of light - close drapes. Air conditioner or ventilator - turn off.

For further ideas, tell us which type of mouse you use. Did I understand correctly that other mice have the same problem? If possible, try another laptop, as well.

Comment: Thanks for good ideas . i tried every indoor places . also tried turning off the wifi by hardware key . also unplugged the power . another mouses on same laptop have same problem . this mouse on another laptop has no problem . another laptop works fine .

Answer (score 1):

Get a mouse pad, if you already have one get a new one.

Check to see if there are cracks or gaps on the surface on which you use the mouse. Try cleaning it.

It definitely has something to do with the surface because it has to be clean, level and flat.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the mouse and the surface you're using it on. If it's wireless, try using a wired one. It may be RF interference.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. Been out of town for a bout 10 days, it was fine. Now it's not. Nothing has changed. Not connected to the web, using wacom tablet. With or without tablet same problem.
But good news, I just made it stop. Not sure what or why, cleaned the wacom mouse and pad, only TINY less vibration. But, when I moved the main computer mouse and adjusted what it was sitting on, it stopped. I think it's the computer mouse causing the trouble, not the wacom as it vibrated with the pen tool.
Thanks for the suggestions. Now if I could just figure out why my cursor on my laptop jumps around the paragraph that would be even better.
win 7, os. thanks